# how to filter date with given timezone in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date, utc, angularjs-filter

this the time format i need to convert with angular, in the format each has its own timezone(at the end starts with +) and i want to filter with related to their timezone.

```
    "2016-09-01T11:15:00.000+01:00"
    "2016-09-01T21:50:00.000+03:00"
    "2016-09-02T07:30:00.000+05:00"
```

what i tried to do was returning me my browser timezone:

```
{{o.ArrivalTime | date:'dd MMMM HH:mm'}}
```

o.arrivaltime is what that gives me the above time stamp.

Comment: Is o.ArrivalTime a date object or a string?

Comment: i have achieved this task @Wake through using filter and then using the substring function to get the time. 
Thanks